# arm_pc in signal handler

Tags: c, arm, gdb, interrupt-handling

Trying to print the faulting instruction address in my signal handler as demonstrated in https://devarea.com/linux-writing-fault-handlers/#comment-12995

for some reason each time I print p->uc_mcontext.arm_pc content I get a different result which doesn't make sense to gdb.
if I run the same program with gdb and print the registers with "info registers" I see a consistent PC value on each run which also allows me to see the faulty code

relevant code in signal handler:

```
static void My_Signals_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *extra)
{

ucontext_t *p;

printf("Received Signal: %d\n", sig);

switch(sig)
{
case SIGFPE:
case SIGSEGV:
case SIGILL:
case SIGBUS:
    p = (ucontext_t *)extra;
    printf("siginfo address=%x\n", info->si_addr);
    printf("arm_pc address = 0x%X\n", p->uc_mcontext.arm_pc);
    printf("arm_sp address = 0x%X\n", p->uc_mcontext.arm_sp);
    printf("arm_lr address = 0x%X\n", p->uc_mcontext.arm_lr);
    printf("arm_r0  address = 0x%X\n", p->uc_mcontext.arm_r0);
    /* make sure buffer is printed to stodut before we crash */
    fflush(stdout);
    /* restore to default signal handler so core dump is generated from original fault point */
    RegisterForSignals(true);
    return;
    break;
default:
    printf("unknown signal %d\n", sig);
    /* restore to default signal handler so core dump is generated from original fault point */
    RegisterForSignals(true);
    return;
}

return;
}
```

output (changes on every run):

```
Received Signal: 11
siginfo address=0
arm_pc address = 0x44D3AE
arm_sp address = 0xBEEFFCC0
arm_lr address = 0x44D3AD
arm_r0  address = 0x0
```

when running with gdb

```
(gdb) info registers                                                  
r0             0x0                 0                                  
r1             0x0                 0                                  
r2             0xffffffff          4294967295                         
r3             0x4bb268            4960872                            
r4             0x494680            4802176                            
r5             0x494ea4            4804260                            
r6             0x0                 0                                  
r7             0x0                 0                                  
r8             0x455               1109                               
r9             0x465               1125                               
r10            0x4946b4            4802228                            
r11            0x4bb168            4960616                            
r12            0x0                 0                                  
sp             0xbefffcc0          0xbefffcc0                         
lr             0x4033ad            4207533                            
pc             0x4033ae            0x4033ae <main(int, char**)+526>   
cpsr           0x40070030          1074200624                         
fpscr          0x0                 0                                  
(gdb)
```

Comment: You cannot call `printf()` (and friends) from a signal handler. It is not signal safe. period.

Comment: I agree, I've removed the prints and stored the data in a global variable, another thread is reading from there but the arm_pc still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the issue was ASLR randomizing the addresses. when I've disabled ASLR the arm_pc address was the same as the one output by gdb.
since this cannot be a perpetual solution I've used the backtrace API to print the backtrace and with it I got the offset from the beginning of my application. that address can be used in gdb.